# camera option not showing in Raspberry Pi configuration - interfaces

Tags: camera

i have a rpi4 and the camera option is not showing in the raspberry pi configuration - interfaces. i have checked for updates etc and re-booted. in the sub menu i go for the option for the camera but still does not show. Help...

Comment: yes i have a camera and it is connected.

Comment: which camera are you using?